# read json output in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to read the http response in python. the response is as below and I need to extract all records out of the specific fields. Below is my json output, i have trimmed it. But I am getting type error. I am new to python not sure what I am missing here.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

My code:

```
data={u'Movies': [{u'Movie': {u'movieID': u'30', u'status': u'released', u'aflag': u'1', u'Type': u'action', u'releasedate': u'1276624', u'moddate': u'1276636', u'name': u'titanic', u'frameflag': u'1', u'class': u'UA'}},{u'Movies': [{u'Movie': {u'movieID': u'32', u'status': u'released', u'aflag': u'0', u'Type': u'action', u'releasedate': u'1276624', u'moddate': u'1276636', u'name': u'movie2', u'frameflag': u'1', u'class': u'UA'}}


data_j=json.loads(data)
for i in data_j['Movies']['data_j']:
    print i['Movie']['name']
```

Comment: Your `data` variable is *already a Python dictionary*. It is not a JSON value. Did you give us the `djata_j` value instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data['Movies']` is a *list* of dictionaries. Loop over that list; there is no `data_j` index in the list:

```
for movie in data_j['Movies']:
    print movie['Movie']['name']
```

Comment: Besides, `data` is already a dictionary, so I don't see how it will pass through `json.loads`.

Comment: @bereal: nope, the MCVE is anything but. But the error message tells us the `data_j` value is what is shown as `data` instead.